# Return a type from a string

Tags: c#

I'm not really sure where to start with this. I am writing a GUI manager for XNA using my entity component model libraries. I want to be able to dynamically import XML documents to GUI forms. The idea I had was to have an attribute `"type"` that contains the type of the control. For example `type="Image"` would tell the parser to make an image. Once it has that it can call it's own XML parsing method to fill in the values. However, I'm stuck at this part.

Consider this document:

```
<Gui>
  <BGImage type="Image">
    <Body>
      <Position>
        <X>0</X>
        <Y>0</Y>
      </Position>
    </Body>
    <ImageRender>
      <Texture>background</Texture>
      <Color>
        <R>255</R>
        <G>255</G>
        <B>255</B>
        <A>255</A>
      </Color>
    </ImageRender>
  </BGImage>
  <CheckBox type="Checkbox">
    <Body>
      <Position>
        <X>20</X>
        <Y>20</Y>
      </Position>
    </Body>
    <TileRender>
      <Index>0</Index>
      <Texture>checkbox</Texture>
      <Color>
        <R>255</R>
        <G>255</G>
        <B>255</B>
        <A>255</A>
      </Color>
    </TileRender>
    <TextRender>
      <Text>Checkbox</Text>
      <Font>spritefont</Font>
    </TextRender>
  </CheckBox>
</Gui>
```

What I am looking to do is have a class parse this XML document and do the following.
Any tags with a type attribute are added to the form as the type they represent. For example, I have an Image class which represents an image, BGImage in the example should make an Image and be added to the form. What I need is a way to relate the type="Image" to the class Image.

I already have a method I use to add entities to the game, my problem lies with a way to make a string a type and instantiate a new entity from that.

What I am looking to do is return a type from a string, and I'm not really sure that is possible. Is there any way to do this in C#, or am I attacking this from the wrong angle?

Comment: Could you please provide some code examples and go deeper into the context of a problem? Thus, we would have more details to give a better, coherent answer to your question.

Comment: The problem is I don't have any code examples, I'm not really sure where to start. I'll see if I can explain in greater detail

Comment: That would be great. Just imagine if you not quite understand the problem, than how hard it is for us) Anyway, thanks for understanding.

Comment: Without seeing something you tried... Try making a `var` variable that gets set using a `switch` statement?

Comment: @Ally The problem with this is, when I add extra GUI components it becomes a pain to maintain the code, since I'll have to add a case conditional for each an every type of GUI component. I figure there has to be an easier way to do this. I added some extra details.

Comment: You could do something like `System.Type.GetType("System.String")` if you're just using system types so it would be `System.Type.GetType("System." + typeVar)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do exactly as you describe by using a C# type qualified name.

For example the qualified name for `System.Drawing.Image` is "System.Drawing.Image, System.Drawing".  The qualified name is made up of a few pieces.  In my example it is [type name], [assembly name].  ([Reference article from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6.aspx))

As long as the assembly that contains the type is loaded into your app domain (in this case the assembly is System.Drawing) you can do the following to instantiate it:

```
var imageType = Type.GetType("System.Drawing.Image, System.Drawing");
System.Drawing.Image image = Activator.CreateInstance(imageType );
```

Comment: Hmm this might work. I need to be able to add the new object to a list. It doesn't need to have a field for it, so it could be `AddEntity(new Image());`. Can I do that with this method?

Comment: Erm no, AddEntity(Activator.CreateInstance(imageType)); would though

Comment: This seems like it will work and I am working on coding a prototype now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favour and store the mapping from the type in your xml, to a concrete type in an assembly in an other resource. Especially if you start defining/extending your own types.

e.g.

```
<Assembly name="System.Drawing", namespace = "System.Drawing">
<Type name = "PrettyPicture", Type = "Image"/>
</Assembly>
```

etc

Put the fully qualified names in the layout file and you'll be all over the place if you want to change anything.

dtyron with his point at Type.GetType and Activator.CreateInstance has pretty much given you a good start on the nuts and bolts.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a full parser. It's not quite as easy as the other solutions but it might be simpler in the long run.

```
    Control Parse(XElement element)
    {
        var root = new XElementControlPair(element, ControlWrapper.Create(element));

        var stack = new Stack<XElementControlPair>();

        stack.Push(root);

        while (stack.Any()) //here we recursively search for any child elements
        {
            var elem = stack.Pop();

            var children = from child in elem.XElement.Elements() 
                           let ctl = ControlWrapper.Create(child)                               
                           where child.Attribute("type") != null 
                           select new XElementControlPair(child, ctl);


            foreach (var child in children)
            {
                stack.Push(child);
                elem.Control.Controls.Add(child.Control);
            }

        }

        return root.Control.MakeControl();

    }

class XElementControlPair
{
    public XElement XElement { get; private set; }
    public ControlWrapper Control { get; private set; }

    public XElementControlPair(XElement elem, ControlWrapper ctl)
    {
        this.XElement = elem;
        this.Control = ctl;
    }
}

abstract class ControlWrapper
{
    public List<ControlWrapper> Controls { get; private set; }
    protected readonly XElement element;

    public ControlWrapper(XElement element)
    {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public static ControlWrapper Create(XElement element)
    {
        var type = element.Attribute("type").Value.ToLower();

        switch (type)
        {
            case "image":
                return new ImageWrapper(element);

            case "textbox":
                return new TextBoxWrapper(element);

            case "checkbox":
                return new CheckBoxWrapper(element);

            //etc...
        }
    }

    protected abstract Control _MakeControl(); //here is where you tell it how to construct a particular control given an XElement

    public Control MakeControl()
    {
        var ctl = _MakeControl();

        foreach (var child in Controls)
            ctl.Children.Add(child.MakeControl());

        return ctl;
    }

}
```

Then for each kind of control you make a wrapper class that handles turning the XML into the specific control. For example:

```
sealed class ImageWrapper : ControlWrapper
{
    public ImageWrapper(XElement element) { } : base(element)

    protected override Control _MakeControl()
    {
        var image = new Image();

        var pos = element.Element("Position");

        var x = int.Parse(pos.Element("X").Value);
        var y = int.Parse(pos.Element("y").Value);

        image.Position = new Point(x, y);

        //continue setting other properties...

        return image;

    }
}
```